# Trouble signing in to visual studio 2019 while using Microsoft 365 from GoDaddy

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to sign in to visual studio using the email myname@mydomain.com while using Microsoft 365 from GoDaddy. All I get is a script error message as per the attached screenshot. The dialogue doesn't go away despite clicking Yes or No, I have to turn off the PC altogether. The domain name is registered with GoDaddy.

I have tried re-installing visual studio, disabled third-party extensions and logged in as administrator with no change.

All help is appreciated to solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that VS uses an embedded browser by default. Just go to Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts and change the dropdown to say "System web browser"

[Options screen showing proper setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj1Ui.png)